# Convert Frame to BufferedImage using JavaCV

Tags: java, image, frame, bufferedimage, javacv

so I have a Frame from a video:

```
FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(videoFilePath);
grabber.start();

grabber.setFrameNumber(frameNumber);
Frame frame = grabber.grab();
```

and I want to convert it to a BufferedImage so currently I am using this:

```
Java2DFrameConverter c = new Java2DFrameConverter();
BufferedImage image = c.convert(frame);
```

But when I am trying to save the .png file like that

```
ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputFrameFile);
```

But I am getting the error "image == null" idk why

I tried to look for answers but nothing helped.

Comment: That just means you don't have an image in that frame. Try with the next frame.